# The Documentation oneboxes don’t look good on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, chat, onebox

Looks like a missing `clear`:

[image: Screenshot]

[see for yourself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDOfT.png)

…then again, maybe it’s me. It’s still
**t**
**o**
**t**
**a**
**l**
**l**
**y** legible, right?

Comment: Sometimes I get annoyed at how high dpi screenshots are so big on SO, but I think it works in this case.

Comment: *don't look good* ... that is just a matter of taste ...

Comment: @rene `example\ns`

Comment: @JF You have [a lot of nerve](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wNX1p.png) pointing that out.

Comment: @Laurel It’s not a pluralization bug — the box is too small for the whole word, so it wraps.

Comment: Wow 100% battery charge level

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon (Almost) always plugged in.

Comment: All I want to know is: why is the next/forward arrow thicker than the previous/back arrow?

Comment: I would tell you to call an expert, but then I saw the flight mode?

Comment: @ShadiNamrouti Saves battery if you don’t want texts or calls. You can still have Wi-Fi & Bluetooth on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex layouts are fun!

I fixed up the styling, so it should be more readable going forward:

[image]

Still a few tweaks we could make there, but at least the onebox is no longer unusable.